# closed form of beta distribution CDF for $\alpha = \beta = 1/2$

Tags: integration

Is there a way of evaluating following integral?

$$F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}} \,dt$$

($x \in [0,1]$)

Wolframalpha did not help but could at least say that $F(1) = \pi$. The problems are obviously the poles at $0$ and $1,$ but it would also be nice to have the lower bound $1/2$ instead of $0,$ as we could use the symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x)$ is the [incomplete Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $B(a,b;z)$ associated with the parameters $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$.

Luckily, it has a closed form expression, given by $\color{red}{2\,\text{arcsin}(\sqrt{x})}$.

That is easy to check by using the substitution $t=u^2$ or just by differentiating $2\arcsin(\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\overbrace{t(1-t) = \frac 1 4 - \left(t-\frac1 2\right)^2}^\text{completing the square} = \frac 1 4\big( 1 - (2t-1)^2\big)
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac 1 {\sqrt{t(1-t)}} & = \frac 2 {\sqrt{1 - (2t-1)^2}} \\[8pt]
& = \frac 2 {\sqrt{1-u^2}} = \frac d{du} \, 2\arcsin u \\[8pt]
& = \left( \frac d {dt} \, 2\arcsin u \right)\cdot \frac {dt}{du}
\end{align}