# Closed form of beta distribution CDF when $\alpha + \beta = 1$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, beta-function

Is there a closed form of the [regularized incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) $I_x(\alpha, \beta)$ when $\alpha + \beta = 1$?

A nice closed form based on arcsin exists for the case where $\alpha = \beta = 1/2$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511786/closed-form-of-beta-distribution-cdf-for-alpha-beta-1-2)). Is there a similar one for the more general case?

My motivation is that I'd like to find, given $p \in [0, 1]$, the $\alpha$ such that the $\Pr(X > 0.5) = p$ where $X \sim Beta(\alpha, 1- \alpha)$. I would like to do this efficiently for any $p \in [0, 1]$ – which should be easy with the closed form of the regularized incomplete Beta function.

Comment: $$
\int_0^x u^{\alpha-1} (1-u)^{-\alpha} \, du
$$

Comment: Is there a neat closed form for this integral? Something that would it straightforward to compute $\alpha$ for a given $p$?

Comment: Maybe you should make that comment a separate question.